# Add content from text file to the end of the content of a variable

Tags: powershell

This is my code:

$tt = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'

I have a txt file c:\temp\reg.txt
The content of the twxt file is:

00000005

Then i would like to add the content from the text file to the end of the variable so $tt 
will be updated to

'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000005'

I don't know how to do it, or if you can.

Thanks for the help

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: I have updated my question, hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution just like on Unix: `$x = "bla bla $(cat file.txt)"`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for me.

$regTest = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'

$regTestNew = (Get-Content C:\temp\NewOutlookSignature.txt)

$path = $regTest

@($regTestNew) | % { $path = Join-Path $path $_ }

Then the output from $path is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000005

Thanks for the help Pete